# RESTful key-value collection

Tags: rest, api, http

I am creating a HTTP REST API. I have a large collection of key-value pairs, at `/base-url`.

I need to provide the ability to get and set values for a key.

My first attempt:

```
GET /base-url/{key}

PUT /base-url/{key}
```

The problem is that this requires URL recipes, which as I understand go against the hypermedia principles of REST.

What is the usual way of providing a key-value store via a RESTful API?

Answer (score 6):

This is allowed by REST as long as your `{key}` URLs are discoverable; for example if doing

```
GET /base-url/
```

returned a list of links to other valid REST resources, and among those were `/base-url/{key}`

The main point is that out-of-band knowledge can't be *required* by a REST-conforming API; but if a provider publishes a specification the client is certainly free to go directly to a URL it already knows about.

I found [this article](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) by Roy Fielding useful to clarify these points, in particular

```
A REST API must not define fixed resource names or hierarchies (an obvious coupling
of client and server). Servers must have the freedom to control their own namespace.
Instead, allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such
as is done in HTML forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within
media types and link relations. [Failure here implies that clients are assuming a
resource structure due to out-of band information, such as a domain-specific standard,
which is the data-oriented equivalent to RPC's functional coupling].
```

This essentially means that if you publish a spec and the client/programmer needs that in order to determine the valid URLs, then you've created an API but it's not a *REST* API. To conform with Roy Fielding's thesis defining REST, you must make those same URLs *discoverable* by starting at the root.

Comment: Since links come and go, it is useful to quote the relevant portion of the article as a part of the answer. You don't need to include the whole article, just the part that supports your answer.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman good point, updated with the most relevant quote to my point.

Comment: Ah, I need to create a key-value pair foo-bar. What do I do then?

Comment: The concept missing in your design is the content type the client will understand in order to figure out how to navigate your key value store. The client should be able to go to base-url and based on the content type of the resource representation it gets back figure out how to navigate your server. Think about HTML with its <a> link tags. You don't need to know where anything is when you go to www.nytimes.com, because your browser understands HTML and can present links to the data you want.

Answer (score 2):

Independent from implementing a key-value-store or whatever: you could use [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) to describe your api. This enrichens the plain ressource information with *meta*-information what to do with your API. So in your example a call to *base* gives a collection of keys and their values:

```
GET /baseurl/
```

gives you a resultset:

```
    [
    {
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://www.yoursite/base"
            },
            "item": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key1"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key2"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key3"
                }
            ]
        },
        "content": [
            {
                "key": "key1",
                "value": "value1",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "key2",
                "value": "value2",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "key3",
                "value": "value3",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "http://www.yoursite/base/key3"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

A simple `GET` against your `baseurl` shows a list of *items* returned. Each with a link (at least) to the single item (or more if you want to relate several keys to other ressources). From that I - as a consumer - know, that there is a ressource `key3` behind the URL `http://www.yoursite/base/key3`. Analogous I know, that I (eventually) could use the typical HTTP-verbs (HEAD, GET,PUT,POST,DELETE, PATCH). But I can query that ressurce for its capabilities via an [*OPTIONS*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9)-Request. Its answer would contain an `Allow`-Section, which shows allowed verbs:

```
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE
```

When implemented in this way, your API becomes very intuitive and selfexplaining (independend from the ressources you offer).